# Ads are not loading in AdView in Landscape Mode Android

Tags: android, adview

I Want to load Google Ads in in AdView in Landscape mode. The ads are loading in Portrait mode but it is not loading in Landscape mode. Please Help

Here is my code for xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <WebView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/web1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

 <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     ads:adUnitId="a151c14ed73ec5f"
                     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     android:gravity="center"     
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_weight="9" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And This code is written in Java:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Please Reply!

AdView is Showing but ads arw not shown in AdView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check the error log may be your adview is not getting proper space required for it..

Comment: How I could know if it is not getting proper space?

Comment: Please do reply How would I know if the AdView is not getting proper space?

Comment: then you can take any linearlayout with the android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainAdsLayout);
  layout.addView(adview);

  AdRequest adrequest=new AdRequest();
  adrequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.LOGTAG);
  adview.loadAd(adrequest);

Comment: But how will I place this adview below the webview?

Comment: RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout( this );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);

Answer (score 1):

You're using all your space for your webview:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Use a RelativeLayout instead, and put the WebView "above" the AdView.

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">


<WebView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/web1"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="a151c14ed73ec5f"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    android:gravity="center"     
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have changed the layout:

Comment: Yes I copied your code. AdView is Showing but the ads are not showing in the ADView. I am just getting a blank ADView

Comment: I don't think you need Java code if you have set everything in the xml, probably that's the problem. Try to remove it. And change `TEST_DEVICE_ID` with yout actual device id.

Comment: I am testing it on Emulator

Comment: Check the logcat. Try it on a real device. Check internet permissions.