# Adview android not appearing in the Landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape, adview

I have my main Activity in Portrait mode. I want to add a Banner Adview in landscape mode. How to achieve this?

Note: I tried using SetRotation(90) to Adview. But it rotates it from (0,0) and banner appears in the centre of the screen. I want some thing like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNUyo.png

Comment: you should check the error log may be your adview is not getting proper space required for it..

Comment: check this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369551/ads-are-not-loading-in-adview-in-landscape-mode-android